# Scroll screen without using UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, scroll

I've seen iOS apps that allow users to scroll around a view that is larger than the screen itself, without seeming to implement a UIScrollView mechanic. So for example, the actual image displayed on the screen is double the width of the screen, and the user can pan left and right to view all the content. Is this just a case of making the ViewController's width twice that of the screen and allowing some kind of panning via gesture recognizers? With what I'm trying to do, it seems like this would be easier that implementing a UIScrollView...

Comment: Perhaps only scrollIndicators were hidden?

Comment: `UIScrollView`s can be made twice the size of the screen and have panning implementation built in.  What are you finding difficult about using a `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing scrollview is much easier than handling pan gesture, when Apple has given built-in functionality then why you do not want to use it?

Comment: Ok... I'll just go with UIScrollView. I guess I just figured there might be a simpler alternative, but it's not that complicated...

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `UIPangestureRecognizer` or `UIscrollview`. The Latter option is very simple.